# Git Bash/mintty - How to enable horizontal scrollbar or set screen buffer size or turn off text wrapping?

Tags: windows, git, bash, git-bash, mintty

Does anyone know how to enable horizontal scrollbar in Git Bash/Mintty shell? Or at least is there a way we can turn off text wrapping or set screen buffer size (like we set in windows command prompt)?

[image]